# How to use a stream as input for Browserify?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, browserify

In Gulp, I'm trying to compile TypeScript, concatenate it, then run it through Browserify to handle the `require`s (then uglify after if in production mode).

[This sample code](https://github.com/toranb/react-gulp-browserify-ts-example/blob/master/gulpfile.js) is the closest I've found to what I'm trying to do, however it uses an intermediary file. I'd much rather keep things to the stream to avoid the overhead of the intermediary file if at all possible.

Since Browserify outputs a stream, it seems like it should know how to accept one as well.

## The relevant code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = requ
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var transform = require('vinyl-transform');
var typeScript = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src([mySrcDir,'typings/**/*.d.ts'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typeScript(typeScriptProject))
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(transform(function (filename) {
            return browserify(filename).bundle();
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(ns.outDir))
        // Reload, notify...
        ;
```

## The result:

`Error: Cannot find module 'C:\path\to\project\root\src\main.js' in 'C:\path\to\project\root'`

When I omit concatenation, the result is the same, except with `foobar.js` instead of `main.js` where `foobar.ts` is one of the input files.

## A second attempt

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    var stream = gulp.src([mySrcDir,'typings/**/*.d.ts'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typeScript(typeScriptProject))
        .pipe(concat('main.js'));
    var bundleStream = ns.browserify(stream).bundle().on('error', errorHandler);
    // and then...
```

## A new error

```
C:\path\to\project\root\_stream_0.js:1
[object Object]
        ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

Comment: So in your source files do you have an entry file that would build a dependency graph incorporating the rest of the files, or do you have a bunch of separate entry files?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. If we have to hit the disk, we are back in Grunt land. Gulp is all about streams. Would like to see this answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a `vinyl` stream to browserify. It only accepts `text` or `buffer` streams. The only solution is to transform the input `vinyl` stream to a `text` stream that browserify can grasp:

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util')
var through = require('through2')
var intoStream = require('into-stream')

// ...
.pipe(through.obj(function(file, encoding, next) {
  bundle = browserify(intoStream(file.contents))
  this.push(new gutil.File({
    path: 'index.js',
    contents: bundle.bundle()
  }))
  next()
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [gulp-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify), it a gulp plugin for browserify.

Example:

```
gulp.src([mySrcDir,'typings/**/*.d.ts'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typeScript(typeScriptProject))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(browserify(options)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(ns.outDir))
    // Reload, notify...
    ;
```

for options you may refer to the link posted above

Comment: I've taken a look at it; gulp-browserify is outdated and blacklisted.

Comment: @Qwertman - oh is it? sorry, i have been using it in my project and got no idea of it's blacklisted

Comment: Yeah, right now it's the only thing I've found to work (so your answer is sort of right - I'll upvote it but not mark it). Thanks for revising and adding more details, too.

There are a lot of people complaining about the blacklist. The main problem is that in response, the maintainer stopped maintaining, so for now we're stuck with an aging version of Browserify that will eventually become incompatible with other modules or possibly Node itself (I'm not confident about the likeliness of either: I don't know enough about the ecosystem so it's a guess at best).

Comment: @Qwertman, as it's open source, try to PR. Or if the author has no response to your PR, build one by yourself :]

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no vanilla solution working for now. [The code in this link](https://github.com/sogko/gulp-recipes/tree/master/browserify-vanilla) fails to work.